# How can I make this reflection code work for any specific case of a generic type?

Tags: generics, reflection, f#

I have some data coming from some system via a TcpClient.

The system is a kind of column store with it's own way of representing null values. The system supports null for any type including int, DateTime etc.

The TcpClient returns values like `DateTime.MinValue` in case of nulls. But the client also has a null checking utility.

I have put together some reflection code to generate types, which works fine as long as I don't have any option types. I want to adapt this code to map null values to `Option<'t>`.

So far, I have the following utility.

```
let checkNull (x:obj) =
    let elementType = x.GetType()
    let defType = typedefof<ValueOption<_>>;
    let genericType = defType.MakeGenericType elementType
    let optionCaseInfoSome, _ = FSharpValue.GetUnionFields(DateTime.Now |> ValueSome :> obj, genericType)
    let valueNone:ValueOption<DateTime> = ValueNone
    let optionCaseInfoNone, _ = FSharpValue.GetUnionFields(valueNone :> obj, genericType)
    if KdbConstants.IsNull x then
        FSharpValue.MakeUnion(optionCaseInfoNone, Array.empty)
    else
        FSharpValue.MakeUnion(optionCaseInfoSome, [|x|])
```

This will only work for `Option<DateTime>` values. How can I adapt this to work for any `Option<`t>`?

PS: I am aware that my utility is not efficient and much of the values can be pre-calculated, rather than being run each time the function is called. I will clean it up once I get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have an answer to this

```
let makeOptionCaseMetaData (x:obj) =
    let elementType = x.GetType()
    let defType = typedefof<Option<_>>;
    let genericType = defType.MakeGenericType elementType
    let optionCaseInfoNone, optionCaseInfoSome = FSharpType.GetUnionCases(genericType) |> (fun a -> a[0], a[1])
    {OptionCaseInfoSome = optionCaseInfoSome; OptionCaseInfoNone = optionCaseInfoNone}

let checkNull (x:obj) =
    let metaData = makeOptionCaseMetaData x
    if KdbConstants.IsNull x then
        FSharpValue.MakeUnion(metaData.OptionCaseInfoNone, Array.empty)
    else
        FSharpValue.MakeUnion(metaData.OptionCaseInfoSome, [|x|])
```

Still not very efficient but I can worry about that separately.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simplify this and avoid using some of the reflection. You can define a normal generic method to do the conversion:

```
// For illustration, turn "" to `null`
let isNull (x:obj) = unbox x = "" 

// Static method (easier to access via reflection) that does the null check
type OptionConverter =
  static member CheckNull<'T>(x:'T) = 
    if isNull x then None
    else Some x
```

If you now get some object, you can create a generic instantiation of `CheckNull` and invoke the method to do the work:

```
let checkNull (x:obj) =
  let checkMi = typeof<OptionConverter>.GetMethod("CheckNull")
  checkMi.MakeGenericMethod(x.GetType()).Invoke(null, [| x |])

checkNull ""    // None (shows as `<null>` in FSI because it is of type `obj`)
checkNull "Yo"  // Some "Yo"
```

Comment: Do you see any advantages to your approach over what I answered? Better performance maybe?

Comment: Note that in my case, the call to `makeOptionCaseMetaData` is factored out.

Comment: I'd prefer my approach mainly because the code is a bit simpler. It may be a bit more efficient (fewere calls via reflection), but I do not think it'll make such a big difference.